# AChartEngine - Y-Axis Grid Lines are not showing properly

Tags: android, achartengine

I have a bar graph generated using AChartEngine. However, I seem to encounter an issue regarding the Y-Axis Grid Lines. As seen in this photo below (not mine), there are lines perpendicular to the Y-Axis along the values and it makes it easy for the user to see the levels.

[image: Example]

My graph, however, only shows those gridlines/level lines for the first two Y-Axis values. Does any one have an idea on how to fix this?

Photo:
[image: My graph]

Here is my code:

```
    //collection of multiple vales for one renderer or series
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(); 

    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    mRenderer.setChartTitle("Sales for " + customerCD);
    mRenderer.setXTitle("\n \n Item Codes");
    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(30);
    mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(30);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(20);
    mRenderer.setYTitle("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n Number of Orders");
    mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    mRenderer.setShowLegend(true);
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(25);
    mRenderer.setShowGridX(true); // this will show the grid in graph
    mRenderer.setShowGridY(true);
    mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setGridColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    // mRenderer.setAntialiasing(true);
    mRenderer.setBarSpacing(.5); // adding spacing between the line or
                                    // stacks
    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
    mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
    mRenderer.setXAxisMax(itemCount + 1);
    mRenderer.setXLabels(0);

    mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    mRenderer.setYAxisMax(max+1);
    //right, top, left, bottom
    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{30,50,100,10});
    //
    mRenderer.setXLabelsPadding(10);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(20);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < ItemCD.length; i++){
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(i+1, ItemCD[i]);
    }
```

//      mRenderer.addXTextLabel(1, "Income");
//      mRenderer.addXTextLabel(2, "Saving");
//      mRenderer.addXTextLabel(3, "Expenditure");
//      mRenderer.addXTextLabel(4, "NetIncome");

```
    mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true, false);


    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false); // will fix the chart position

    //xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax
    mRenderer.setPanLimits(new double[]{0, itemCount + 1, 0, max + 1});
    mRenderer.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
```

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your chart as well.

Comment: There, added a screenshot of my graph.

Comment: This may be a bug for such VERTICAL bar charts. http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=203